# jquery toggle function open/close

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to do a function that does "A" when toggle open and "B" when toggle close.

Code:

```
function awesome_toggle()
{
    $(".button").click(function()
    {
        $("content").toggle(
            function()
            {
                /* Do "A" */
            },
            function()
            {
                /* Do "B" */
            }
        );
    });
}
```

This code doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out why. When I use only one function, so I stop the code after /* Do "A" */ it works but when I add the /* Do "B" */ function it stops working. What is wrong?

jquery version: ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js

Comment: is this your complete JS?

Comment: @Mooseman If you are implying this should be re-tagged as a JavaScript question (adding the JS tag) I think you should do that. Also, OP, I'm not sure I understand the question, specifically what you'd like done.

Comment: This two-function version of toggle was removed in jQuery 1.9.1. Have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/. I believe it is now interpreting the first function as something else (e.g. a duration) and throw an error.

Comment: @user2084627: That version of `toggle` was deprecated, and it was removed in jQuery 1.9.1. Perhaps that's the problem? Also, "pretty much" really isn't good enough.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you including?

Comment: also, how are you calling awesome_toggle()

Comment: @Felix, ah ok. So how do I do that now?

Comment: function is call, yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the comments have said, this version of `toggle` has been deprecated.

There may very well be a better way to accomplish what you want, but you *can* check whether the element is visible after toggle with the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector, and do stuff conditionally based upon that.

```
function awesome_toggle()
{
    $(".button").click(function() {
        $("content").toggle(normalSpeed, function () {
            if ($("content").is(':visible')) {
                /* Do "A" */
            } else {
                /* Do "B" */
            }
        });
    });
}
```